# I keep getting this error int cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

The code is supposed to return the first and the last letter of a string ,but I keep getting these errors Line 5: int cannot be dereferenced and Line 6: int cannot be dereferenced

```
public String firstAndLast(String str)
  {
  int length = str.length();
  char first= length.charAt(0);
  char last= length.charAt(length - 1);
  return String.valueOf(first) + String.valueOf(last); 
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not

```
char last= length.charAt(length - 1);
```

but

```
char last= str.charAt(length - 1);
```

More important, the error message is telling you exactly where your problem is -- which line, and what's wrong -- you're trying to call a method on length, an int. In the future, read the error messages critically as they'll usually give you the problem and a solution can be obvious once you understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much i was going crazy i didn't think that would change anything :) I can't choose answer right now but when it lets me i will

Comment: @TheCompile: you're welcome, and remember, the key is to look *critically* at the involved line and to strive to understand what the error message is telling you. Once you understand it, fixing the issue here is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

length is a primitive type int variable. You can not invoke methods through it, maybe the code would be in this way?

```
    public String firstAndLast(String str)
    {
        int length = str.length();
        char first= str.charAt(0);
        char last= str.charAt(length - 1);
        return String.valueOf(first) + String.valueOf(last); 
    }
```